# How to find out most used sold book category in a specific month

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate the category that has sold the most copies (in books) for a specific month - say january. My payment_date column is in datetime format. It says I have an error in my SQL syntax with the following query

```
SELECT category_id, SUM(payment_amount) AS Total FROM Payments GROUP BY category_id WHERE MONTH(payment_date) = 01 ORDER BY SUM(payment_amount) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Help us help you - please share the table's structure, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for that sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GROUP BY part of the statement needs to come after the WHERE clause, so your query should be:

```
SELECT category_id, SUM(payment_amount) AS Total FROM Payments WHERE MONTH(payment_date) = 1 GROUP BY category_id ORDER BY SUM(payment_amount) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!